# My contact form - I've changed the source code but the changes are not being applied

Tags: theme-development, customization, contact

I obviously found the file responsible of displaying the contact form with `FireBug`, changed the displayed names in the input area and then re-upload my file, however, nothing was changed.

The input value of the first area was `your name`, i changed it to `votre nom`, but still displying me `your name`. You can check it in this [url](http://www.patisserie-orient.fr/zconsulting/), you can use FireBug to check this. Here is a sceenshot, and I'm use the *Boldy* theme:

[image: Screenshot of form and firebug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are overidding your values in [custom.js](http://www.patisserie-orient.fr/zconsulting/wp-content/themes/boldy/js/custom.js):

```
$('#quickName').val('your name');
$('#quickEmail').val('your email');
$('#quickComment').val('your message');
```

Remove these lines and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanx a million, it works like a sharme :)